# ignoring null or Optional.empty values when mapping

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

Is there to map this, rather than looping through it?
There are cases in which the value should not be put in the map, so I want to ignore those:

```
Map<A, String> returnMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<A, List<Long>> mapLByA = //...
mapLByA.forEach((k, v) -> {
    Optional<String> strOp = someMethod(v);
    if (str.isPresent()) {
        returnMap.put(k, strOp.get());
    }
});
return returnMap;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map the list values to optional string values, then filter out the empty optionals, and finally collect to a map. You don't need to explicitly define `returnMap`.

```
return mapLByA.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> Map.entry(e.getKey(), someMethod(e.getValue())))
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().isPresent())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

**Edit:**

`Map.entry` was introduced in Java 9. For Java 8, use this map statement instead:

```
.map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), someMethod(e.getValue())))
```

Comment: Map.entry? That's strange, there is no such method in Map, an Map.Entry is abstract? Can this be refactored?

Comment: @CCC It was introduced in Java 9. You can use `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` if you're using Java 8.

Comment: great thanks. Just a minor detail collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().get()));

Answer (score 2):

You still need to loop, either externally or internally, no way around it. But you could simplify that code to a single line, cannot tell if it makes it more readable though:

```
mapLByA.forEach((k, v) -> someMethod(v).ifPresent(s -> returnedMap.put(k, s)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `ifPresent` in the context as :

```
mapLByA.forEach((k, v) -> 
        someMethod(v).ifPresent(optional -> 
                returnMap.put(k, optional)));
```

Comment: Seems more readable(related) to me as compared to the `map`ping.